# Jquery Draggable

Tags: jquery, html

i'm new to **jquery** .I have problem in the following code .I saved it as a html file but the **Draggable box** is not visible in the browser.Do i want to install "**UI Draggable plugin**"
Where i went wrong ....

```
<style type="text/css">
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>
</head>



<div class="demo">

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me and</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: have you included jquery and ui files??

Comment: needd script <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> and dragable

Comment: can u plz tel me, how to include ui files

Comment: @KumarHtabmas: this is online script http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js   and jQuery UI 1.8.18
also visit my demo link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/QhVNr/

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

Comment: thanks satinder singh,Devjosh,mithilatw, AlphaMale                           It worked after adding  ui files ("<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>")

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the jquery UI script File in your page 
otherwise it is working all fine 
see it working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FT3Uw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drag and Drop, you have to follow following steps:

1) Include Latest JQuery and JQuery UI javascript Files as well as also include JQuery UI CSS

2) Write HTML:

```
<div id="demo-frame">
    <div class="demo">
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable">
            <p>Drag me to my target</p>
        </div>
        <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header ui-droppable">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

3) Apply CSS:

```
#demo-frame {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    clear: right;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 520px;
}
#demo-frame .demo {
    padding: 5px;
}

#draggable { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  padding: 0.5em; 
  float: left; 
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; 
}

#droppable { 
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px; 
  padding: 0.5em; 
  float: left; 
  margin: 10px; 
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background: url("http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/?new=eeeeee&w=1&h=100&f=png&q=100&fltr[]=over|textures/03_highlight_soft.png|0|0|100") repeat-x scroll 50% top #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #333333;
}
```

4) Write JQuery Script:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
```

I have created bins for drag and drop on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpdd